# Text refusing to resize despite using @media query

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was putting together a site using bootstrap and I wanted the text to resize when it was viewed in on a phone in portrait mode:

So I used the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

   h1 {
      font-size: 3em;
   }

   h5 {
      font-size: 2em;
   }
```

However for some reason that I can't fathom the text is not resizing when viewed on a mobile.

Thanks in advance

full code here:
https://github.com/MrVIncentRyan/portfolio

Comment: Have you tried to use `rem` instead of `em`. `em` is relative to the element it's used in where as `rem` isn't

Comment: I have tried using px and percentages with no success!

Comment: I just tried your code in a snippet and it works well. Your example is not enough detailed to be reproduced.

Comment: I understand that the snippet should work. It is correct. However it is clashing with either bootstrap or something else that is causing it not to work. That is the element that I can't figure out.

Comment: I have ended up fixing using flex boxes. However the media query is still not working for some reason!

Comment: Just inspect and see what's overriding it or if the styles are being applied at all

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this wasn't working but I have fixed it by changing the flexbox that the text was in.